# Is there a way to render sprites in Corona SDK/Solar2D in the upper left corner rather than the center?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

It's really annoying and confusing since I am used to pygame and Figma.
[image]

Comment: Pretty sure Solar2D uses the regular coordinate points, can you provide the code you used to position the sprites?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. By default the anchor points are positioned in center of object. To change the anchor point use `anchorX` and `anchorY` properties

```
local display_object = ...
-- upper left corner
display_object.anchorX = 0
display_object.anchorY = 0

-- down right corner
display_object.anchorX = 1
display_object.anchorY = 1

-- center 
display_object.anchorX = 0.5
display_object.anchorY = 0.5
```

Read more

- [Transforms and Anchors](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/graphics/transform-anchor.html#transforms-and-anchors)
- [object.anchorX](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/anchorX.html)
- [object.anchorY](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/anchorY.html)
- [Extending Anchor Points](https://docs.coronalabs.com/tutorial/media/extendAnchors/index.html)

Have a nice day:)

Comment: Is there a way to do it automatically to every object? Thanks anyways.

Comment: Yes. Use (for left top corner) `display.setDefault("anchorX")=0` and `display.setDefault("anchorY")=0` to set default anchor values. See [Display Object Keys](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/setDefault.html#display-object-keys) for more information.